# Xamarin Android ActivityAttribute Name and LaunchMode fields for Google search app indexing

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Context is: Xamarin Android for Visual Studio 2015 SP2.

The question concerns the general rules one should follow specifying the values for the `Name` and `LaunchMode` parameters of `Android.App.ActivityAttribute`

Here is how my code looks now:

```
[Activity(
    Label = "Полиглот 16", 
    Icon = "@drawable/icon", 
    MainLauncher = true, 
    ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation,
    HardwareAccelerated = true,
    Theme = "@style/PolyglotSplash")]
```

Now I am planning to make my app and app's content searchable by Google search and bound to my website via deep links.

In [this example](https://blog.xamarin.com/connect-with-your-users-with-google-search-and-app-indexing/) I see that the `Name` and `LaunchMode` fields are set for the `ActivityAttribute`. [Documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Android.App.ActivityAttribute.Name/) for the `Name` attribute says:

> The name of the class that implements the activity.

and even more obscure remarks. In the example code the `Name` is set to:

> com.refractored.monkeysapp.MainActivity

This does not look like the .NET fully qualified class name that implements the activity. This looks like the package name followed by the activity name. Is this what is meant to be put in the `Name` attribute field?

Second question is about the `LaunchMode` field. I did not care for this field before because my app has one activity and it is the launch activity. I do not plan to create any additional activities. Do I have to worry about the `LaunchMode` for my activity in new scenarios involving app indexing by Google search and deep links from my web site to my app's content?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this? My app doesn't run when I try to add an `ActionAttribute` with the `Name` parameter. I wonder if you should even need it if you're adding the attribute to the correct class.

Comment: @JamieKitson Yep, I used trials and errors method to build up the activity attributes. Got away with the name set to Name = "ru.noxx.polyglot16.MainActivity" and left the `LaunchMode` unset i.e. default.